# How can I find the matching values from a column within 3 or more grouped dataframes?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have grouped data frames (in my case three data frames grouped together ).  I want to find the intersection between all three data frames based on a value in a column.

I have been playing around with the dplyr intersect function but don't see how I can use this with my grouped data frames.  I want to find all rows within all three data frames that have the same Start.Coord value.

Here is one failed attempt with the resulting error message:

```
SameWithinTreatment <= SorbitolGroup %>% group_by(Sample) %>% intersect(Start.Coord)
Error in intersect_data_frame(x, y) : object 'Start.Coord' not found
```

Obviously I need another parameter to give to intersect().  I see that intersect() doesn't seem to be the function I need but it seems that there must be a way to do what I need.

I have done a lot of searching but everything I find only works with 2 data frames.

Here is some example data from my grouped data frames.  There is one row with a common Start.Coord value between these three: the row with 8805 as the Start.Coord.

```
  Start.Coord Stop.Coord Sample      Coverage normalized.coverage Average.Normalized.Covera~ SD.of.Normalized.Covera~ TwoSD
        <int>      <int> <chr>          <int>               <dbl>                      <dbl>                    <dbl> <dbl>
1        1019       1023 X1.combined       19                  18                       9.91                     3.98  7.95
2        1510       1514 X1.combined       19                  18                       9.91                     3.98  7.95
3        1514       1518 X1.combined       19                  18                       9.91                     3.98  7.95
4        1520       1524 X1.combined       19                  18                       9.91                     3.98  7.95
5        8805       8809 X1.combined       19                  18                       9.91                     3.98  7.95
6       48185      48189 X1.combined       19                  18                       9.91                     3.98  7.95

  Start.Coord Stop.Coord Sample Coverage normalized.coverage Average.Normalized.Coverage SD.of.Normalized.Coverage TwoSD
        <int>      <int> <chr>     <int>               <dbl>                       <dbl>                     <dbl> <dbl>
1       8805      8809 X2          167                 166                        122.                      21.7  43.4
2       11874      11878 X2          169                 168                        122.                      21.7  43.4
3       12042      12046 X2          169                 168                        122.                      21.7  43.4
4       18321      18325 X2          175                 174                        122.                      21.7  43.4
5       25187      25191 X2          167                 166                        122.                      21.7  43.4
6       25308      25312 X2          194                 193                        122.                      21.7  43.4

  Start.Coord Stop.Coord Sample Coverage normalized.coverage Average.Normalized.Coverage SD.of.Normalized.Coverage TwoSD
        <int>      <int> <chr>     <int>               <dbl>                       <dbl>                     <dbl> <dbl>
1        8805       8809 X3          132                 131                        94.4                      16.7  33.5
2       10340      10344 X3          135                 134                        94.4                      16.7  33.5
3       11874      11878 X3          141                 140                        94.4                      16.7  33.5
4       12042      12046 X3          137                 136                        94.4                      16.7  33.5
5       18209      18213 X3          133                 132                        94.4                      16.7  33.5
6       18218      18222 X3          143                 142                        94.4                      16.7  33.5
```

So I would like to get back a new data frame that looks like this:

```
Start.Coord Stop.Coord Sample Coverage normalized.coverage Average.Normalized.Coverage SD.of.Normalized.Coverage TwoSD
8805       8809 X1.combined       19                  18                       9.91                     3.98  7.95
8805      8809 X2          167                 166                        122.                      21.7  43.4
8805       8809 X3          132                 131                        94.4                      16.7  33.5
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your 3 data frames have the same column names use `rbind` to combine them 
`SorbitolGroup<- rbind(df1,df2,df3)`
then add 
`Start.Coord` to `group_by`:

`SorbitolGroup %>% group_by(Sample,Start.Coord)`

If you want to count the number of observations in both groups

`SorbitolGroup %>% group_by(Sample,Start.Coord) %>% tally()`

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you need to use `filter()`, in addition to what @W148SMH suggested.

```r
a <- data.frame(sample='a',value=sample(1:10,10,T))
b <- data.frame(sample='b',value=sample(1:10,10,T))
c <- data.frame(sample='c',value=sample(1:10,10,T))

df <- rbind(a,b,c)
summary(df)

df %>% filter(value==9)
df_new <- df %>% filter(value==9) # new data frame including all cases with value==9

df %>% count(sample,value)

df %>% group_by(sample,value) %>% 
  summarise(...) # to summarise other variables at each level of sample and value
```